# meaning of description for constructor of property class

Tags: java

For property class we have the following as one of the constructors:

```
Properties(Properties default)
    Creates an empty property list with the specified defaults
```

What does it mean by "empty property list with the specified defaults"

I wrote a demo program to test what is happening:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    private static String z;
    private static String i;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        z = "a";
        i = "b";
        Properties p = new Properties();

        p.setProperty("z",z);
        p.setProperty("i",i);
        p.store(new FileOutputStream("r.txt"), null);

        Properties pp = new Properties(p);
        pp.store(new FileOutputStream("random.txt"), null);
        pp.load(new FileInputStream("in.txt"));
        pp.store(new FileOutputStream("random1.txt"), null); 
    }
}
```

The result were `random.txt` was empty, `random1.txt` has `z=n`. The newly created property has no defaults as `random.txt` is empty. So what does the constructor description mean? Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: To: "What does it mean by "empty property list with the specified defaults"" my guess would be that, if another property with the same key as the default one is not added to this newly created list, but the user attempts to get the property by key, then the default is returned. If the key (with a new value) is later on added to the list, and the user attempts to get the property by same key, it now returns the new value.

Comment: @EvgheniCrujcov: Would be what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the `store` documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), default properties (the ones passed in the `Properties(Properties)` constructor) are not written to the external file. Apparently you thought they would be (a reasonable assumption).

The following test:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Properties p = new Properties();

        p.setProperty("z", "z value");
        p.setProperty("i", "i value");

        Properties pp = new Properties(p);
        pp.setProperty("i", "some other value");

        System.out.println(p.getProperty("z"));
        System.out.println(p.getProperty("i"));
        System.out.println(pp.getProperty("z"));
        System.out.println(pp.getProperty("i"));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
z value
i value
z value
some other value
```

If you need to include defaults when you `store`, one option would be to extend `Properties` with your own class and override `store` to output default properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

It means that when it cannot find the property at runtime, it will fall back to the default Properties, it is not a copy constructor.

You might want to consider using [.putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Properties pp = new Properties(p);`

> This allows for arbitrary nesting of levels of default properties.

for example

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("z","hello");
    p.store(new FileOutputStream("D://java1.properties"), null);
    Properties pp = new Properties(p);
    pp.setProperty("y","world");
    System.out.println(pp.getProperty("z")); //prints hello
```

if you call `pp.getProperty("z")` on `PP` object, and *"z"* does not exist, Java looks for *"z"* in the default Properties object that is `P` object,there it finds *"z"* and prints its value *"hello"*

For more details please have look [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=376)